# What's the relation between the covariance estimation of the full dataset VERSUS the covariance estimations of the resampled/bootstrapped set

Tags: covariance, covariance-matrix, central-limit-theorem, resampling

Consider the following Matlab code:

```
    close all;
    clear;
    clc;
    rng('shuffle');

    nbrOfSamples = 100000;        
    nbrOfsubsets = 10000; 
    samplesPerSubset = floor(nbrOfSamples / nbrOfsubsets);        

    mu = [2,3];
    sigma = [1,1.5;1.5,3];        
    rawsamples = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,nbrOfSamples);

    rawResult = det(sigma);

    rawCenter = mean(rawsamples);

    detresult = nan(nbrOfsubsets, 1);
    meanresult = nan(nbrOfsubsets, 2);
    for idx=1:nbrOfsubsets
        subset = rawsamples(randperm(nbrOfSamples, samplesPerSubset), :);            
        detresult(idx, :) = det(cov(subset));
        meanresult(idx, :) =  mean(subset);
    end

    figure;
    subplot(2,1,1);
    histogram(meanresult(:, 1));
    line(rawCenter(1) * [1 1], get(gca,'YLim'), 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', 'r');
    line(mean(meanresult(:, 1)) * [1 1], get(gca,'YLim'), 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', 'g');

    subplot(2,1,2);
    histogram(meanresult(:, 2));
    line(rawCenter(2) * [1 1], get(gca,'YLim'), 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', 'r');
    line(mean(meanresult(:, 2)) * [1 1], get(gca,'YLim'), 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', 'g');

    figure
    histogram(detresult);
    l1=line(rawResult * [1 1], get(gca,'YLim'), 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', 'r');
    l2=line(det(cov(rawsamples)) * [1 1], get(gca,'YLim'), 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', 'b');        
    l3=line(mean(detresult) * [1 1], get(gca,'YLim'), 'LineWidth', 1, 'Color', 'g');
    legend([l1 l2 l3], '|\Sigma_{theoretical}|', '|\Sigma|_{full dataset}', '|\Sigma|_{pooled}');
    xlabel('|\Sigma|');
```

In this script a bivariate normal distribution is uniform subsampled using 10.000 subsets. For each subset the covariance and the mean are calculated. Finally, all covariance estimations are merged to one final estimation \Sigma|*{pooled}

These estimations are also performed for the full dataset - without subsampling - yielding \Sigma|*{full dataset}.

The covariance determinants of given estimations are plotted below:
[image: determinant of pooled covariance matrix versus determinant of full set covariance matrix]

As one can clearly notice in the depicted result, the determinants of the covariance estimations seems to follow a Wishart distribution - a generalization to multiple dimensions of the chi-squared distribution - whereas the mean is normal distributed (according to the CLT).

Does anyone know if (and how) it's possible to use the resampled distribution to obtain an estimate that is more or less equal to |\Sigma_{full}|, i.e the determinant of the covariance matrix of the full set?
Any references to good literature are also highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't completely understand your problem but I will give you a recent reference on resampling to estimate a covariance matrix.  It is for time series analysis so I don't know how much is relevant to you but at least it gives you a lot of reputable references.

Comment: The reference is "Covariancce Matrix Estimation and Linear Process Bootstrap for Multivariate Time Series of Possibly Increasing Dimension." Annals of Statistics 2015 Carsten Jentsch and Dimitris Politis (authors).  A direct link to the pdf is https://arxiv.org/pdf/150600816.pdf .

Comment: This link doesn't seem to work from this site.  However I got it through a Google search for bootstrapping covariance matrices.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the link! Bottom line of the problem is that the bootstrapped covariance matrix estimation is not equal to the covariance of the full dataset; especially for small bootstrap sample size, the distribution looks skewed and the final bootstrapped, pooled covar is an underestimation of the 'true' covariance. How is this possible and how can this be solved?